# Why is R reading numeric data as character?

Tags: r

I'm trying to load a file that contains integers and float data. I'm at a loss as to why R will read one of the columns as a character field.

```
 > df <- read.table( 'C:\\temp\\test.tab' , 
 +                   sep = '\t' , header = TRUE , stringsAsFactors = FALSE , dec="." )
 > str(df)
 'data.frame':  7 obs. of  5 variables:
  $ A: int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  $ B: int  1431 2097 2712 24821 27359 41165 49221
  $ C: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  $ D: chr  "7" "26.950000762939453" "57.95000076293945" "21" ...
  $ E: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

---

### File Content:

```
 A  B   C   D   E
 0  1431    0   7   1
 0  2097    0   26.950000762939453  2
 0  2712    0   57.95000076293945   3
 0  24821   0   21  4
 1  27359   0   57.900001525878906  5
 0  41165   0   33.95000076293945   6
 0  49221   0   28.950000762939453  7
```

---

[image]

```
 > R.version
           _                           
 platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
 arch           x86_64                      
 os             mingw32                     
 system         x86_64, mingw32             
 status                                     
 major          3                           
 minor          1.0                         
 year           2014                        
 month          04                          
 day            10                          
 svn rev        65387                       
 language       R                           
 version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
 nickname       Spring Dance
```

Comment: My guess is that you're seeing the new behavior in `?type.convert` in R 3.1.0. See the Details section. There has been an extensive discussion about this change on the r-devel mailing list.

Comment: (I believe the default behaviour has also been reverted in the development version ...) e.g. https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/3e07d22cfaa259e935e2d891b02349b192ca11b1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This probably deserves a genuine answer that we can point to, so....

The behavior of `type.convert` was altered in R 3.1.0 (and, read below, will be largely reverted to its pre-3.1.0 behavior in R 3.1.1):

> As from R 3.1.0, where converting inputs to numeric or complex would
>   result in loss of accuracy they are returned as strings (for as.is =
>   TRUE) or factors.

This created a fairly significant ruckus on the r-devel mailing list. The beginning of the relevant (and long) thread is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-April/068778.html).

As Ben mentioned above, one of the results of that discussion is that the default behavior was [restored](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/3e07d22cfaa259e935e2d891b02349b192ca11b1) in the development version for a subsequent release.

In the short term if you know which columns will be affected you can always use `colClasses`. Otherwise you'd have to modify your code to check the results of `read.table` and convert things yourself, I guess.

Comment: Thank you. Hope we'll get the option of turning this feature on/off. Parsing the data and keeping only 5 decimals solved the problem. Going back into existing scripts, parsing out factors vs. numerics vs. characters and then running `as.numeric()` isn't a very good option.

Comment: `awk -F$'\t' '(NR==1){ print }(NR>1){  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){ if( !match($j,/[a-zA-Z]+/) ){ $j=sprintf("%.5f",$j) }    }  print}'`